# Ошибка при отправке формы

Tags: javascript, ajax

код работы с формой:

```
//form
    let message = new Object();
    message.laoding='загрузка...';
    message.succes='Мы с вами свяжемся в течении часа!';
    message.error='Упс Что-то пошло не так';

    let form=document.getElementsByClassName('main-form')[0],
    input=document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
    status_message=document.createElement('div');
    status_message.classList.add('status');
    console.log(form);

    form.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        form.appendChild(status_message);

        //ajax
        let request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST','server.php');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-ww-form-urlencoded');

        let data = new FormData(form);

        request.send(data);

        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (request.readyState < 4){
                status_message.innerHTML=message.laoding;
            }
            else if (request.readyState == 4){
                if (request.status == 200 && request.status < 300){
                    status_message.innerHTML=message.succes;
                    //добавляем что-нить
                }
                else{
                    status_message.innerHTML=message.error;
                }

            }
        }
        for(let i =0; i < input.length; i++){
            input[i].value='';
            //очищаем поля ввода
        }
    });

    // ДЛЯ Нижней формы
    let mes=new Object();
    mes.laoding='загрузка...';
    mes.succes='Мы с вами свяжемся в течении часа!';
    mes.error='Упс Что-то пошло не так';
    let forms_1 = document.getElementsByClassName('contact-form')[0];
    let forms_2=document.getElementById('form');
    stats=document.createElement('div');
    stats.classList.add('status');
    let input_1=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    console.log(input_1);
    console.log(forms_2);
    forms_2.addEventListener('submit',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        forms_2.appendChild(stats);

        let request=new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST','server.php');
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-ww-form-urlencoded');
        let data = new FormData(forms_2);
        request.send(data);
        request.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if (request.readyState < 4){
                stats.innerHTML=message.laoding;
            }
            else if (request.readyState == 4){
                if (request.status == 200 && request.status < 300){
                    stats.innerHTML=mes.succes;
                    //добавляем что-нить
                }
                else{
                    stats.innerHTML=mes.error;
                }

            }
        }
        for(let i =2; i < input_1.length; i++){
            input[i].value='';
            //очищаем поля ввода
        }
    });
```

ошибка здесь: 1 для верхней  `Access to XMLHttpRequest  from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`
2 для нижней:`Access to XMLHttpRequest at from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

```
var data = new FormData(forms_1);
```

forms_1:

```
<form action="#" class="main-form">
                        <div class="popup-form-header">
                            Узнайте больше о своём отдыхе
                        </div>
                            <label class="popup-form__label" for="phone">
                            Введите ваш номер телефона:
                            </label>
                            <input class="popup-form__input" name="phone" type="tel" required="" placeholder="+7(978) 973 33 45">
                            <button class="button popup-form__btn">
                                Оставить заявку!
                            </button>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Если понадобится что-то ещё я напишу в комментариях или изменю вопрос.

Comment: Текст ошибки говорит сам за себя: `forms_1`  не HTML-форма.

Comment: так мне выдаёт что это html форма посмотри выше, тогда почему проблема и как исправить?

Comment: `forms_1`  - `div` элемент, а не форма. форма - внутри.

Comment: а где в коде вообще ваша переменная forms_1 создаётся? Вижу `let form=document.getElementsByClassName('main-form')[0]` а дальше вы уже на forms_1 вешаете события

Comment: там просто для 2-x форм могу скинуть для обоих и вы посмотрите ошибка опять же с data а именно не работает send.